# Best practice for time derived properties in Java

Tags: java, performance, date, jakarta-ee, time

Java applications are said to have the habit to request the current time excessively. Here is one piece of code I wrote back more then a decade:

```
public class Event {
    public String name;
    public Date startTime;
    public Date eventStartTime;
    public Date presaleStopTime;
    public Date presaleStartTime;

    /** Specific start time set? */
    public boolean isPresaleNotYetStarted() {
        if (presaleStartTime == null) { return false;}
        Date now = new Date();
        return now.before(presaleStartTime);
    }

    /** Specific end time set? If not, presale starts immediately */
    public boolean isPresaleTerminated() {
        if (presaleStopTime == null) { return false; }
        Date now = new Date();
        return now.after(presaleStopTime);
    }

    Date getLatestPossibleShipmentDate() {
        Date now = new Date();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(eventStartTime);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);
        return c.getTime();
    }

    /** The ticket can still be delivered to the customer */
    public boolean isShipmentPossible() {
        Date now = new Date();
        return now.before(getLatestPossibleShipmentDate());
    }

    public boolean isTicketInPresale() {
        return isShipmentPossible()
            && !isPresaleNotYetStarted()
            && !isPresaleTerminated();
    }
}
```

While this is a perfectly crafted piece of code regarding readability, it has obviously some issues with testability, consistency and performance.

To make the story complete, here is how the web tier looks like with abstraction and implementation hiding ideas applied:

```
<% Event event = ...; %>
<% if (event.isTicketInPresale()) { %>
... display order button...
<% } else {
       // display some meaningful reason to the customer,
       // why ordering is not possible
       if (event.isPresaleTerminated()) {
%>Sorry, presale is terminated<%
       } else if (!event.isShipmentPossible() && new Date().before(event.startTime)) {
%>Sorry, shipment of the tickets is not possible any more.<%
       } else if (!event.isPresaleNotYetStarted()) {
%>Presale not yet started, come back later<%
       }
   }
%>
```

When this code runs, it will request the current time for about 8 times, in the worst case.

What is a good best practice solution or implementation pattern for this?

I tag the question also with J2EE, since this may be a common problem in business applications.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Aside: When ever I see the words "good practice" or "best practice" in a Question, I get the feeling that the questioner is looking for a "cookie cutter" solution that allows him / her to *NOT THINK* about the problem / solution.</sup>

Ignoring the "good practice" issue ... the real problem with using multiple different date instances for "now" is that it is conceptually wrong.  You have two alternatives that make logical sense.  Either you model the "now" of your request as a single indivisible point in time, or you model it as a duration; e.g. corresponding to the start and end of your request's processing.  The first approach is simpler, and the more complicated approach will rarely offer any practical benefit.

On the basis of the above, I think that the most sensible *conceptually correct* solution is for all of the API methods to have the same "now".   The simple way to do that is to have all methods business logic that involved "now" take an explicit "now" date parameter.  The caller (e.g. your JSP) is then responsible for creating a "now" date and using it consistently in all of the method calls that need it.

The most important property of this solution is that it is correct.  By contrast, each time one of your current methods does a `new Date` it will get a slightly different timestamp.  If your application runs "on the cusp" of the start or end of an `Event`, then you might get unexpected behaviour.

My proposed solution also affects performance and readability ... but correctness and reliability should trump those other concerns.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! The paradigm "time is a parameter" is essentially the thing we do now for many years. The question is "best practice" not because we don't think for ourselves, the question is for "best practice", because I never came across this problem in all the literature about patterns, good coding and testing. And, I saw many "interesting" concepts, to do tests with time dependent code, like having an own time source that can be detuned.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine if you had some sort of desired resolution (like say 5 to 10 secs) you can essentially create a singleton object that will give you the current time and cache it every 5 to 10 seconds.  Below is a quick attempt at that.

```
public class CacheDate {

    private static final CacheDate instance = new CacheDate();
    public static final long CACHE_INTERVAL = 10_000;
    private final AtomicBoolean finished = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private volatile Date curDate;

    private final Thread updateTime = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!finished.get()) {
                try {
                    curDate = new Date();
                    Thread.sleep(CACHE_INTERVAL);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }

    };

    private CacheDate() {
        startUpdatingTime();
    }

    public static CacheDate getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void stopUpdatingTime() {
        finished.set(true);
        updateTime.interrupt();
    }

    public void startUpdatingTime() {
        finished.set(false);
        updateTime.start();
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return curDate.getTime();
    }

    public boolean after(Date when) {
        return curDate.after(when);
    }

    public boolean before(Date when) {
        return curDate.before(when);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jose! Yes, that is a feasible approach for enhancing performance, since actually the business related times have minute resolution. As Stephen pointed out, it does not address the problem of testability.

Comment: Whats the testing scenario?  You can mock this class using Mockito if you want to test code using it.  Testing this class itself is not too bad either... I would just edit to allow a configurable caching interval so that your unit tests do not have to wait long if you are forcing a cache update.

Comment: Your proposed source of time is a global singleton. If I want to mock it, then I need to make the "time source service" a parameter.

Comment: Correct.  Normally what I do for singletons like this is create a public static setMockObject(mockObj) which will take the place of the static instance variable when getInstance() is called.  I left that out of this version for brevity.  PowerMockito also has mechanisms for mocking static methods, though I have not yet had the pleasure to use them.